# The data type produced by the sizeof operator

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, sizeof

I was told by someone much more knowledgeable than me that the sizeof operator does not produce a value of type "size_t" but instead produces a value having the same underlying type as "size_t".  While this may be nothing more than a semantic technicality, C++11 5.3.3.6 and C++14 5.3.3.6 both state the following:

```
The result of sizeof and sizeof... is a constant of type std::size_t.
[ Note: std::size_t is defined in the standard header <cstddef> (18.2). —end note ]
```

I interpret this to mean that if there were a way to display the data type of a sizeof expression it should display "std::size_t" or "size_t" rather than "unsigned int", "unsigned long" or whatever size_t happens to represent on that particular compiler, and it should display "std::size_t" or "size_t" even if there were no typedef of size_t in scope because the compiler internally knows it is size_t.

However, if my interpretation is incorrect and it would instead be correct for the underlying data type to be displayed, shouldn't C++11 and C++14 instead say something like:

```
The result of sizeof and sizeof... is a constant of **the same type represented** by std::size_t.
```

I realize this may be arguing over the number of angels on the head of a pin but I would still like to understand which is legalistically correct.

Thanks,
Ray

Comment: On your implementation `size_t` is likely to be the same as `unsigned long` and the compiler knows that.

Comment: "Representation" is not a good choice here. It is not unusual for `unsigned int` and `unsigned long` to have exactly the same representation, but they are still distinct types. `std::size_t` is just a name, meaning "the type returned by sizeof".

Answer (score 3):

std::size_t is a *typedef-name* or *type alias*, that is a synonim of some other existing type; it's not a distinct type and exists only for the purpose of name lookup.

so, for example, you cannot overload/specialize/etc... against size_t VS its underlying type ...

that said, it's true that the compiler internally knows what an alias is, so it can use it, say, to improve its diagnostics and such and so may ( or may not ) appear in compiler produced messages in place of/along with its underlying type as an aid to the programmer ...